# Extending a Ruby class with a standalone piece of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance

I have a Rails app with several models with the same structure:

```
class Item1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  WIDTH = 100
  HEIGHT = 100
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {original: "#{WIDTH}x#{HEIGHT}"}
  validates_attachment :image, :presence => true
end


class Item2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  WIDTH = 200
  HEIGHT = 200
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {original: "#{WIDTH}x#{HEIGHT}"}
  validates_attachment :image, :presence => true
end
```

The actual code is more complicated but that's enough for simplicity.

I think I can put the common part of the code in one place and then use it in all models.

Here is what comes to my mind:

```
class Item1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  WIDTH = 100
  HEIGHT = 100
  extend CommonItem
end

module CommonItem
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {original: "#{WIDTH}x#{HEIGHT}"}
  validates_attachment :image, :presence => true
end
```

Obviously it doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `CommonItem` has no idea about class methods I invoke.
2. `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` constants are looked up in `CommonItem` instead of `Item1`.

I tried to use `include` instead of `extend`, some ways of `class_eval` and class inheritance, but none work.

It seems I am missing something obvious. Please tell me what.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html is made for stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
class Model
  def self.model_method
    puts "model_method"
  end
end

module Item
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      p base::WIDTH, base::HEIGHT
      model_method
    end
  end
end

class Item1 < Model
  WIDTH = 100
  HEIGHT = 100
  include Item
end

class Item2 < Model
  WIDTH = 200
  HEIGHT = 200
  include Item
end
```

The `included` method is called on a module when it's included.

I think I've managed to create a similar structure that your problem has. The module is calling the method inherited by the items classes from `Model` class.

Output:

```
100
100
model_method
200
200
model_method
```

Comment: Nice! Using `self.included` hook did not come to my mind.. That's a solution for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, the construct to use to extract repeated code into a single unit is a *method*:

```
class Model
  def self.model_method
    p __method__
  end

  private

  def self.item
    p self::WIDTH, self::HEIGHT
    model_method
  end
end

class Item1 < Model
  WIDTH = 100
  HEIGHT = 100
  item
end

class Item2 < Model
  WIDTH = 200
  HEIGHT = 200
  item
end
```

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain? This code solves the OP's problem perfectly, it has the exact same behavior as @Dogbert's code while being much simpler and not requiring any form of metaprogramming, reflection or hooks.