# Extracting common ActiveRecord code for similar clases

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, inheritance, composition

I have the following classes defined that have a lot of common code with minor variations.

```
class ThirdPartyComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :prev_version, :class_name => 'ThirdPartyComponent', :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'
  has_one :next_version, :class_name => 'ThirdPartyComponent', :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'

  attr_accessible :name, :version, :installer, :install_script

  mount_uploader :installer, ComponentFileUploader
  mount_uploader :install_script, ComponentFileUploader

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :version, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\z/ }
  validates :installer, :presence => true
  validates :install_script, :presence => true
  validate :increased_version

  def increased_version
    # Check to ensure that version number is greater than the previous version number for the same component set
    unless prev_version.nil?
      version > prev_version.version
    end
  end 

  def all_previous_versions
    prev_versions = all_versions
    prev_versions.shift
    prev_versions
  end

  def all_versions
    current_version = self
    all_versions = [current_version]
    while !current_version.prev_version.nil?
      all_versions << current_version.prev_version
      current_version = current_version.prev_version
    end
    all_versions
  end
end

class RegistryComponent < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :prev_version, :class_name => 'RegistryComponent', :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'
  has_one :next_version, :class_name => 'RegistryComponent', :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'

  attr_accessible :name, :version, :registry_file

  mount_uploader :registry_file, ComponentFileUploader

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :version, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\z/ }
  validates :registry_file, :presence => true
  validate :increased_version

  def increased_version
    # Check to ensure that version number is greater than the previous version number for the same component set
    unless prev_version.nil?
      version > prev_version.version
    end
  end

  def all_previous_versions
    prev_versions = all_versions
    prev_versions.shift
    prev_versions
  end

  def all_versions
    current_version = self
    all_versions = [current_version]
    while !current_version.prev_version.nil?
      all_versions << current_version.prev_version
      current_version = current_version.prev_version
    end
    all_versions
  end
end
```

I'm also looking at adding some other components in the future, again with very similar functionality.

I want to extract the common code from these classes into a single file (including the ActiveRecord method calls such as validates, etc.) and then just reference them in the concrete classes.

So far I've tried,

1. inheritance - I created a base class that inherited from ActiveRecord and then each class inherited from the base class. Result: Rails complained that it couldn't find a database table whose name matched the base class.
2. inheritance - I considered creating the base class as tableless model instead (see http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) but then I realised that the concrete classes would also be lacking the full ActiveRecord functionality
3. composition - I tried defining the common code in a module and then using include or extend in the concrete classes to access it as shown below.

   ```
   module ComponentBase
     belongs_to :prev_version, :class_name => self.class.name, :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'
     has_one :next_version, :class_name => self.class.name, :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'

     attr_accessible :name, :version

     validates :name, :presence => true
     validates :version, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\z/ }
     validate :increased_version

     def increased_version
       # Check to ensure that version number is greater than the previous version number for the same component set
       unless prev_version.nil?
         version > prev_version.version
       end
     end

     def all_previous_versions
       prev_versions = all_versions
       prev_versions.shift
       prev_versions
     end

     def all_versions
       current_version = self
       all_versions = [current_version]
       while !current_version.prev_version.nil?
         all_versions << current_version.prev_version
         current_version = current_version.prev_version
       end
       all_versions
     end
   end

   class RegistryComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
     include ComponentBase

     attr_accessible :registry_file

     mount_uploader :registry_file, ComponentFileUploader

     validates :registry_file, :presence => true
   end
   ```

   This resulted in an error that the `belongs_to` method is not defined for `ComponentBase`. This looks the most promising solution but is there any way to execute the ActiveRecord class methods within the context of the class that includes them? Alternatively, is there a better way for me to achieve the same aims?

Answer (score 1):

Your first option was actually the best option. Rails uses Single Table Inheritance, which means the data for all of your subclasses is kept in the same table which is why you got the error you did.

What you should do is create a new model called `Component` and add to it all the fields that are common across all of your components as well as one extra field called `type` that should be a string field.

Your Component model will then have all the common fields, logic, and validations.

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Then have have each of your compontent classes subclass Component.

```
class ThirdPartyComponent < Component
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need the belongs_to method to run on the class that is including the module, not the module itself.

Check out module#included http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-included, which will allow you to run code on the module you are including your module into.  Remmeber that Module is an ancestor of Class so this works for classes and modules.

In this case you will want to run belongs_to on the class that the module is being included into, so something like the following should act as an example you can work off of:

```
module ComponentBase
    def self.included(mod)
        mod.class_eval do
            belongs_to :prev_version, :class_name => self.class.name, :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: See my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the following answer at [Extending a Ruby class with a standalone piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333256/extending-a-ruby-class-with-a-standalone-piece-of-code) and with a bit of experimentation got it to work. So the final code I ended up with was,

```
module ComponentBase

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      belongs_to :prev_version, :class_name => base, :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'
      has_one :next_version, :class_name => base, :foreign_key => 'prev_version_id'

      attr_accessible :name, :version

      validates :name, :presence => true
      validates :version, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\z/ }
      validate :increased_version
    end
  end

  def increased_version
    # Check to ensure that version number is greater than the previous version number for the same component set
    unless prev_version.nil?
      version > prev_version.version
    end
  end

  def all_previous_versions
    prev_versions = all_versions
    prev_versions.shift
    prev_versions
  end

  def all_versions
    current_version = self
    all_versions = [current_version]
    while !current_version.prev_version.nil?
      all_versions << current_version.prev_version
      current_version = current_version.prev_version
    end
    all_versions
  end
end

class RegistryComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ComponentBase

  attr_accessible :registry_file

  mount_uploader :registry_file, ComponentFileUploader

  validates :registry_file, :presence => true
end
```

The solution was to use the `included` callback which is called each time the module is included somewhere else. Then, call `class_eval` on the base module to run the methods in the class context (i.e. as class methods). The trickiest part was getting the class name in this context but it simply turned out that I could use `base` (not entirely sure why this is the case but it works).

Comment: base is the class that you are including the module into.

Comment: @Puhlze I saw your answer before you removed it and I think its slightly easier to understand than my own although you have to change `self.class.name` to `base` in both solutions.

Comment: I'll add it back and correct it to include the class_eval method so it's clear what's being discussed in the comments. 'base' in your answer is the parameter being passed into the method.

Comment: The answer you added back won't actually work. The reference to `self.class.name` in the `belongs_to` call references the **module** rather than the class including the module. So, it was fine without the `class_eval` (and I thought it looked cleaner too), it just needs to update the reference